# Getting error "'aspectRatio' must be provided for remote images" when using a local image

Tags: astrojs

Getting an error of `'aspectRatio' must be provided for remote images`  when using a local image even when importing in frontmatter when using the @astrojs/image integration. The imported image is in `/src/images`

As far as I can see this is exactly the same as the example provided in the [@astrojs/image docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/image/#responsive-pictures). I have also even tried the inline import method, but it still hasn't worked.

```
---
import { Picture } from "@astrojs/image/components";
import florence from "../images/florence-3.jpg";
---

<section class="showcase">
  <div class="showcase-bg">
    <Picture
      src={florence}
      widths={[200, 400, 800]}
      sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
      alt="Florence Smith Project Manager Picture"
    />
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working example with a code same as yours

- Astro SSR with node standalone
- Node 16 (Node18 yields a fetch failed issue so not compatible yet with the integration)

see detailed environment in the repo

`/pages/picture.astro`

```html
---
import MyPicture from '../components/MyPicture.astro';
---
<MyPicture/>
```

`MyPicture.astro`

```html
---
import { Picture } from '@astrojs/image/components';
import florence from "../assets/test.png";
---
<Picture
  src={florence}
  widths={[200, 400, 800]}
  sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
  alt="Florence Smith Project Manager Picture"
/>
```

github repo : https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples#16_images

Stackbltiz : https://stackblitz.com/github/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples/tree/main/16_images

the first link `/picture` is working
[image]